# Searching Date Fields

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have a query that looks for a search term in certain fields of Data Model.

```
eventsQuery.where = 'Name contains :SearchTerm OR ' +
                    'Description contains :SearchTerm OR ' +
                    'ID contains :SearchTerm OR ' +
                    'Owner contains :SearchTerm';
```

I want to add the Date field into the search.

```
'Date contains :SearchTerm OR ' +
```

What would be the proper way to do so? FYI "Date" is already defined as a date field in the Data Model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is possible to do with Query Builder, but it looks like it works with [Calculated SQL Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#sql_calculated_model):

Your SQL query would look similar to this:

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  Name,
  Date
FROM
  Test
WHERE
  Name LIKE :SearchTerm OR
  Date LIKE :SearchTerm OR
  MONTHNAME(Date) LIKE :SearchTerm OR
  DAYNAME(DATE) LIKE :SearchTerm
```

**Notes**

To make it work for dates your search terms should look like this

- `2018-12-31%` - to search for exact date
- `%2018%` - to search for all 2018 year's records
- Full month name (e.g. January, February, March, ect...)
- jan% (for all months that start with 'jan')
- %uary (for all months that end with 'uary')
- %r% (for all months that contain 'r')
- same logic to search dates with specific days

Feel free to learn more about pattern matching in MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Inside your you can either educate your users to this query syntax or smartly analyze and format search term before passing it to the search query. You can find complex Calculated SQL search query sample in [Project Tracker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/) template. I would also consider using `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE` depending on your search requirements.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, the query I'm referencing was taken from the Project Tracker template. That is the template I'm working from. The search term would come from the user's input and therefore would not always be entered in any specific format. Maybe I could turn the actual date into a string format, and then search that?

Comment: Most likely you are looking at Drive Tables based version of Project Tracker, I would recommend to take a look at Cloud SQL version as well. If you have real date (for instance from Datebox widget), then I think you can introduce one more query parameter: `...Name contains :SearchTerm OR Date = :Date...`

Comment: I've upgraded to SQL. but with that method, would the parameter :Date have to be in a date format? and therefore I'd need to convert the SearchTerm into a Date. Would it not be easier to something like...
`eventsQuery.where = 'Name contains :SearchTerm OR ' +
                        'Description contains :SearchTerm OR ' +
                        'ID contains :SearchTerm OR ' +
                        'DATENAME(month, Date) contains :SearchTerm OR ' +
                        'Owner contains :SearchTerm';  `

Comment: In theory it should work as well (but I'm not sure if `DATENAME` is supported by MySQL).

Comment: David, I've updated SQL query to accommodate the case from your previous comment. I also noticed, that in your comment you shared Query Builder expression (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_builder) opposed to ***real SQL query*** that you can write up with Calculated SQL model (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#sql_calculated_model). Please, make sure that you had a look at the ***SQL version*** of the Project Tracker template to be on the same page with me =).

Comment: thanks Pavel! I converted my entire Search setup to the method used in SQL Version of Project Tracker.